# Recursively search registry in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, search, registry

I have a problem with my search registry function. My goal is to enter key name and traverse registry tree until key with this name is found. My function could walk the whole tree (depth-first), but the problem is with searching - I only can successfully search for keys on the "first level". But if I try to search, for example, for HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes, "Schemes" key will be skipped. For searching I use the found flag and the idea is to continue search while it set to false. But nor if (!found) { //function code }, nor while (!found) did seem to work out for me. What did I miss and how to solve it?

My code is:

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 400

void searchKeys(HKEY, string, TCHAR*, bool);

int main()
{
    HKEY rootKey= HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
    int keyMenu;
    TCHAR searchedName[BUFF_SIZE];
    bool found = false;


    cout << "Select root key: " << endl;
    cout << "1 - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\n2 - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\n3 - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\n4 - HKEY_USERS\n5 - HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG"<<endl;
    cin >> keyMenu;

    switch (keyMenu) {
    case 1: rootKey = HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
        break;
    case 2: rootKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
        break;
    case 3: rootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
        break;
    case 4: rootKey = HKEY_USERS;
        break;
    case 5: rootKey = HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG;
        break;
    default: 
        cout << "This root key does not exist" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }


    cout << "Enter key name to search: " << endl;
    cin >> searchedName;
    cout << "\n";

    string subKeyPath = "";

    searchKeys(rootKey, subKeyPath, searchedName, found);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void searchKeys(HKEY rootKey, string subKeyPath, TCHAR* searchedName, bool found) {
    HKEY subKey;
    DWORD subKeyCount, buffSize;
    char subKeyBuff[BUFF_SIZE];
    char result[BUFF_SIZE];

    TCHAR sbNameBuf[BUFF_SIZE];
    const char * subKeyName;
    subKeyName = subKeyPath.c_str();
    copy(subKeyPath.begin(), subKeyPath.end(), sbNameBuf);

    //if (!found) {
    //while (!found) {
        DWORD output = RegOpenKeyEx(rootKey, subKeyName, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &subKey); //open specified root catalogue

        if (output != ERROR_SUCCESS) return;

        RegQueryInfoKey(subKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, &subKeyCount, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); //get info about root key

        if (!subKeyCount) return;

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < subKeyCount && !found; i++) {
            buffSize = sizeof(subKeyBuff);
            RegEnumKeyEx(subKey, i, subKeyBuff, &buffSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            string keyName = subKeyBuff;

            if (strcmp(subKeyBuff, searchedName) == 0) {
                found = true;
            }
            else {
                cout << subKeyBuff << endl;
            }

            keyName = subKeyPath + subKeyBuff + "\\";
            RegOpenKeyEx(rootKey, subKeyName, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &subKey);
            RegQueryInfoKey(subKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, &subKeyCount, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); //get subKeyCount

            if (subKeyCount) {
                searchKeys(rootKey, keyName, searchedName, found);
            }

        }
    //}
    //}

}
```

Comment: Possible problem: your algorithm is doesn't update the registry yet you open your subkeys with KEY_ALL_ACCESS. Try KEY_READ.

Comment: That doesn't help and I don't see how it could help, as it's considering security questions

Comment: Like I said it's a 'Possible problem'. The thing is you're trying to find something (assuming no updates) but there may be subkeys to which you don't have write-privileges ,so KEY_ALL_ACCESS will prevent you accessing them and you'll miss potential hits on you search.

Comment: I see. Thank you. But unfortunately this wasn't the case :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this issue was simply making bool found variable global. Also, engf-010 comment was useful for viewing ALL keys.